# How to use Angular Formly Schematics to generate real forms

Tags: angular, angular-formly, angular-schematics

Is it there an angular schematic to generate HTML forms?

I heard of [Formly](https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly) as being a schematics but I don't need to use  tag/component. How to get the HTML  code generated so one can edit them.

PS: found [this good option](https://github.com/mandhu/ngx-starter-crud) but it's based on material package that I don't prefer. would like bootstrap instead